# What's the idiomatic way to implement a multi-edit function, allowing edits for multiple simultaneous fields in a list, in .Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, crud

I'm trying to create an MVC form which will allow a user to edit multiple records at the same time, and submit the changes as a batch update to my data. The code below shows you how I'm displaying the data to be edited. Is this supposed to work out of the box? Should the user be able to click "Submit" and have my "Update" message receive a model containing all of the appropriate changes?

If not, then what's the idiomatic way to implement something like this in .Net MVC?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm( "Update", "SomeController", Model)) {
  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <ul id="categoryEditor" style="list-style-type: none">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AList.Count(); i++) {
          @Html.HiddenFor( model => model.AList[i].ID )
          @(Model.AList[i].Name)
          @Html.EditorFor( model => model.AList[i].Category )
        }
      </ul>

      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: For reference, in the implementation above, the Update function on SomeController receives an empty model as its argument.